# How to get the get timezone from current time?

Tags: php

I am getting the current time as 2010-05-20 06:23:44 format.I want to find the timezone format like(GMT+5.30 chennai).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)** function for that:

```
date_default_timezone_set(''Europe/London''); // change as per your needs
```

But first check if this function exists:

```
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
  date_default_timezone_set(''Europe/London''); // change as per your needs
}
```

You could also use **[`putenv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php)** like this:

```
 putenv ('TZ=Europe/Amsterdam');
 mktime(0,0,0,1,1,1970)
 echo date("H:i:s");
```